# Reading Data from database and storing the data in a List

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm reading some data from a database (information on properties) and i store the information in Property objects. I put the objects in a list of type Property and i display the contents of the list in a listbox. However instead of getting different data for each object I'm getting the same data multiple times. Ps. I instantiate the Property object inside the while loop and the issue persists.

```
void fillListBoxWithProperties()
    {
        List<Property> propList = new List<Property>();
        db_connection();
        MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand();
        cmd.CommandText = "select * from property ";
        cmd.Connection = connect;
        MySqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        while(dr.Read())
        {
            Property prop = new Property();
            prop.PropId = Convert.ToInt32(dr["propertyId"]);
            prop.Address = dr["Address"].ToString();
            prop.PropType = dr["PropertyType"].ToString();
            propList.Add(prop);

        }

        foreach(Property details in propList)
        {
            lstBoxProperties.Items.Add(String.Format("{0} {1}", details.PropId, details.Address));
        }


    }
```

[What the list box prints](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WXnis.jpg)

If i add this code to the loop just for testing:

```
Property prop = new Property();
            prop.PropId = Convert.ToInt32(dr["propertyId"]);
            prop.Address = dr["Address"].ToString();
            prop.PropType = dr["PropertyType"].ToString();
            propList.Add(prop);
            //added code
            foreach (Property o in propList)
            {
               Console.WriteLine(o.toString());
            }
```

The result in the console is the following:

Ballyare,
Rathmulan,
Rathmulan,
Letterkenny,
Letterkenny,
Letterkenny,
Convoy,
Convoy,
Convoy,
Convoy,
Gweedore,
Gweedore,
Gweedore,
Gweedore,
Gweedore,
Glenties,
Glenties,
Glenties,
Glenties,
Glenties,
Glenties,

Property Class Code:

```
class Property
{
    private static int _propId =0;
    private static string _address="";
    private static string _propType="";
    public Property()
    {

    }

    public int PropId
    {
        get { return _propId; }
        set { _propId = value; }
    }
    public string Address
    {
        get { return _address; }
        set { _address = value; }
    }
    public string PropType
    {
        get { return _propType; }
        set { _propType = value; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Put a breakpoint on the foreach loop of propList. How many items are in the propList collection?

Comment: there are 6 records in the database so it's 6.

Comment: simply try using 'lstboxProperties.DataSource = propList; ' instead of foreach loop

Comment: But he's not binding to a data source(Could be better to use binding) so it's no needed.

Comment: it throws an error when I use lstboxProperties.DataBind();

Comment: Are the items in the collection different? I remember having an issue with .Read() where it wasn't moving on to the next row, but simply kept using the same row, so you could end up with 6 duplicate properties. Also from memory DataSource and DataBind() can be troublesome with what it will accept as a datasource. I think you're doing it correctly with items.add

Comment: I've added something to the question that might help perhaps

Comment: Could you stick that foreach test outside of the while and output the PropId and Description for each and let me know what it displays?

Comment: it prints:           6 Glenties, 
6 Glenties, 
6 Glenties, 
6 Glenties, 
6 Glenties, 
6 Glenties,

Comment: @Gino Yeah !! my mistake Databind() should not be used . I removed it.

Comment: Try adding dr.NextResult(); inside your while, after adding the prop to the collection, what does it output then?

Comment: it prints out the first record only

Comment: Looking at Microsofts explanation here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/haa3afyz(v=vs.110).aspx it shows .NextResult() after the while, give that a try and see what you get.

Comment: same as before, just the first record

Comment: Check your database whether it has  unique record or not

Comment: Try to make a breakpoint in the line `prop.PropId = Convert.ToInt32(dr["propertyId"]);` and inspect the values in prop as well as in the list items. Then make one step and inspect again. If all values in the list change, then somehow (I don't know how this could be) `new Property()`does not create a new instance of the class, so you are always modifying the same instance. But as I said, I don't know how this could happen with the shown code, except your don't show us your exact production code.

Comment: I used the breakpoint and what it does is that every time i assign a value it assigns it to the Object prop but also at the same exact time it changes the values of all the the objects in the list. that is why there are 6 of the same records at the end. I have no idea how this is happening and the code i have supplied is identical to what i have.

Comment: Show us the code of the property class then

Comment: The property Class code has been added now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, now after you added the `Property` class, it's quite clear why all of your instances seem to have the same content. You made your private members holding the data `static`. So they don't exist separately for each instance but only once for all instances of the class. Remove the `static` keyword (and see some introduction for what it does)

Comment: OMG. I feel so dumb. sorry for bothering everyone who tried to help, i appreciate it. I don't know why i had that in in the first place.

Comment: @javabanter It's not a problem. Such things happen to all of us from time to time. PS please don't forget to accept, if it solved your problem

Comment: I'm sorry but I'm new to this so i don't know what you mean by accept and how do I do it...